# ANTLR4 - Tree pattern matching code error

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I basically follow the step of the answer in the url:[ANTLR 4 - Tree pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527919/antlr-4-tree-pattern-matching). However, I get the error:

Error:(29, 5) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JavaLexer
  location: class Main.

My code is exactly same. It seems like Java does not know that JavaLexer is. Can anyone help me?

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.pattern.ParseTreeMatch;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.pattern.ParseTreePattern;

import java.util.List;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String source = "package sampleCodes;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "public class fruits {\n" +
            "\n" +
            "  static { int q = 42; }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "  public static void main(String[] args){\n" +
            "    int a = 10;\n" +
            "    System.out.println(a);\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}\n";

    JavaLexer lexer = new JavaLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
    JavaParser parser = new JavaParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    ParseTree tree = parser.compilationUnit();

    ParseTreePattern p = parser.compileParseTreePattern("<IDENTIFIER> = <expression>", JavaParser.RULE_variableDeclarator);
    List<ParseTreeMatch> matches = p.findAll(tree, "//variableDeclarator");

    for (ParseTreeMatch match : matches) {
      System.out.println("\nMATCH:");
      System.out.printf(" - IDENTIFIER: %s\n", match.get("IDENTIFIER").getText());
      System.out.printf(" - expression: %s\n", match.get("expression").getText());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us the commands you ran to run ANTLR and compile the generated classes and to compile and run your `Main` class.

Comment: I don't use commands to compile and run my code. I use IntelliJ and import some packages to run it. Is that the reason why I get the error?

Comment: I am an ANTLR novice. Am I supposed to use commands to get the lexer and parser java file before I run my program? Forgive me

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate the lexer and parser classes first. Do the following:

1. download the ANTLR JAR: https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.8-complete.jar (place it in the same folder as your `Main.java` file)
2. also in this folder, download the Java grammar files: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/java/java/JavaLexer.g4 and https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/java/java/JavaParser.g4
3. open a terminal, navigate to the folder you've downloaded the files and generate the lexer and parser classes from the Java grammar:

   ```
   java -jar antlr-4.8-complete.jar *.g4
   ```
4. compile all `.java` source files:

   ```
   javac -cp antlr-4.8-complete.jar *.java
   ```
5. run the `Main` class:

   ```
   # For Mac & *nix
   java -cp antlr-4.8-complete.jar:. Main

   # or on Windows
   java -cp antlr-4.8-complete.jar;. Main
   ```

The following will be printed on your console:

```
MATCH:
 - IDENTIFIER: q
 - expression: 42

MATCH:
 - IDENTIFIER: a
 - expression: 10
```

Comment: For step 5, I run the command for Windows and I get the error:
Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
    or  java [options] -m <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
       java [options] ..................................................................
To specify an argument for a long option, you can use --<name>=<value> or
--<name> <value>.
bash: Main: No such file or directory.


Is the difference between the command for Mac and the command for Windows just  " ;  " ?

Comment: Yes, the difference is `:` for Mac/*nix and `;` for WIndows. However, if you're using Git Bash on Windows, or similar, you could try the one with `:` instead.

Comment: One more question: If I want to know if a source code includes a specific pattern, like two variables exchange values  
`int a = 1; int b = 2; int temp = a; a = b; b = temp;` 
how do I do this? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I think your current question is answered. If you have more questions, feel free to create a new one. Be sure to add the things you already tried in it.